# Selenium Webdriver Python: I can't seem to locate all the text in a label tag

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
<label class="control-label">
   Rental Charge:
   <span class="required" ng-show="vm.rentalInfo.reason">* (Min of $30.00)</span>
</label>
```

I used

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@ class = 'control-label']/span[@class = 'required']").text
```

and the only `text` I get back is the `asterisk *`, `(Min of $30.00)` is not displayed. 
Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: are you sure both text present inside the same `span` or your locator is unique??

Comment: This is too broad of a locator and you might matching a different element. Try making your locator more specific, for instance: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[ng-show*="rentalInfo.reason"]')`

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur, the html is exactly as I put in the description.

Comment: @alecxe I tried you code, it would even run. however, i tried using css_selector driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.required").text it only picked up the asterisk again.

Comment: I really appreciate your quick responses. I also want to mention that '$30.00' changes depending on the selection from a drop down menu.

Comment: Then you should probably wait until this text to be present, try alecxe suggested answer..:)

Comment: I tried that and i got hit with TimeoutException.

Comment: Is provided timeout enough to show amount??

Comment: Try once as `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.required").get_attribute("textContent")` or `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.required").get_attribute("innerHTML")` and let me know..

Comment: Both returned the same thing, just the asterisk only.

Comment: Thank you guys!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I finally got it!!! this is what i just tried and it worked driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-show = 'vm.rentalInfo.purpose']").text

Comment: So means you didn't provide correct element HTML. In the provided HTML `ng-show` attribute has value `vm.rentalInfo.reason` while you're using to locate `vm.rentalInfo.purpose`. Anyway glad to hear, you have found it finally..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, no, its vm.rentalInfo.reason. That was just a typo. The real solution was being more specific. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is a timing issue. [Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for "$" to be present in element explicitly with `text_to_be_present_in_element` expected condition:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elm = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[ng-show*="rentalIn‌​fo.reason"]'), "$"))
print(elm.text)
```

Comment: Its not a timing issue. I tried what you suggested and i got a TimeoutException. Its crazy.

Comment: @Tosyneno then, you might not be doing something required for the amount to show up. Difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is the issue in your case, it it is not timing issue. You should try using `get_att‌​ribute()` as below may be it helps :-

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.required[ng-show*='rentalIn‌​fo.reason']").get_att‌​ribute("textContent"‌​)
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.required[ng-show*='rentalIn‌​fo.reason']").get_att‌​ribute("innerHTML")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to be a little specific like @alecxe suggested. So i used xpath *driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-show = 'vm.rentalInfo.reason']").text* and it gave me the whole text "* (Min of $30.00)". Thanks to Saurabh Gaur and alecxe for your responses.